# Error in receiving notification when app is in background using "Adhoc Provisioning Profile"

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

We are developing an iPhone app with notification functionality. 
We have created both development and distribution provisioning profile.

First we tested with development profile and app works perfectly fine. We receive notification when app is in background(in active) i.e. we receive both alert and badge counter increases on new notification.

When we tried with Distribution (Adhoc) Provisioning profile we are not getting any alert nor badge counter increases when our app is in background.
But when our app comes to foreground (active mode) we get all the notifications.

We have followed following link to test the app using Adhoc profile.

[Beta Testing Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

How to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: What are you using on the server-side? 3rd party like Urban Airship?

Comment: Nope, i am using APNS

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app in device as a debug mode, than only development profile will work to send notification.

But IF you try with distribution provisioning profile to send notification, than you must have to run app in Distribution mode.It doesn't work if your app is run in debug mode.

Comment: Did this help Solve your problem?